# Как подключить библиотеку C++ к C# проекту?

Tags: c#, c++, opengl

У меня есть проект на C#. Мне нужно построить изогнутый цилиндр.
Я нашёл такую библиотеку

> https://github.com/linas/glextrusion

Но не могу понять, как её использовать в своём проекте.

Comment: Вот аналогичный вопрос с готовым решение : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276389/confused-over-dll-entry-points-entry-point-not-found-exception

Comment: @Inermetso увы там всё необитаемо, "надерганный" код и всё на английском

Comment: здесь глянь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/977715/261244

Answer (score 0):

К С# нельзя подключить .lib (C++) на прямую, но есть несколько решений.

Возможно кому-то пригодится:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/651516/Exposing-native-to-managed-Cplusplus-CLI-vs-P-Invo#secondApproach

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223186/c-cli-wrapper-for-native-c-to-use-as-reference-in-c-sharp